# Illustration of an Instantiation of my "Meta-Model" (UML)

Tags: uml, modeling

For a paper I'm writing I create a `meta-model` and I want to illustrate how this `meta-model` can be `instantiated`.

A simple `meta-model` would look like

[image]

It defines that a `model space` consists of a set of problems whereby a problem can be of a class `A` or `B`.

The instance of it could look like

[image]

Here is the problem, I take the set of all homework assignments and the different assignments (essay vs math) can be of type `A` or `B`.
So the way I have seen it in some paper is, that the `meta-model` classes were displayed using `<<notation>>` (below or above the instance class name).

After doing some research I noticed that the `<<notation>>` is actually for stereotypes. So now i am little confused, whether that is, what I want. What do you think what a good notation for this kind of problem could be?

Comment: I don't get it. You define a meta model and then you decide to look elsewhere to take a different one?

Comment: Why not use instance specifications of the meta-types?

Answer (score 0):

The notation using the << >> signs is common to meta-types and stereotypes. This notation also used for meta-types defined by the UML standard. They are often confused with stereotypes, but in fact, they are no stereotypes. This notation is used because there not that many different shapes and apparences for elements as UML needs. Or would it be bettor to have dashed boxes with two round corners or something similar? So from readability point of view this notation is better. And this notation is applied in the same way to user defined meta-types. So your proposal is correct and there is no need for a different notation (which not not be compliant to the standard).

Comment: What we see in the picture #2 above IS a stereotype as it had been defined (partially shown) in the meta model above it.